# Log convexity and the gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, gamma-function

I am writing an essay on the gamma function. I have learnt and understood convex theory and how the log-convex nature of the gamma function makes it a unique extension of the factorials (Bohr-Mollerup).
However, I am still a little unsure as to the real intuition regarding log-convexity. I have read it as an indication of the extreme smoothness of a function if it is log-convex. But why is this? Is it because of the seemingly smooth nature of the $ln$ function?

Explanations would be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look for example at arxiv.org/pdf/1408.6715 "More convex functions using Artin's method". Log-concave densities are also interesting in probability.